# Overriding core functions in child theme

Tags: functions, theme-development, child-theme

Is it good practice to use children functions.php to override parent core functions?

Example in Storefront theme :

**Core function**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper' ) ) {
    /**
     * The primary navigation wrapper
     */
    function storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper() {
        echo '<div class="storefront-primary-navigation"><div class="col-full">';
    }
}
```

**children functions.php**

```
  function storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper() {
      // modified content;
  }
```

Comment: depends on your programming style. 
It´s made possible for being used, isn´t it?

Comment: The only reason `if ! function_exists(` is even there is to allow you to do this, so yes, it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, that is what `Child Themes` are meant to be, you have the need to modify the theme, but you shouldn't do it directly on the theme since the updates will mess you up, instead, you do all your customizations and new features on your Child Theme so you will be alright.

From [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

> If you modify a theme directly and it is updated, then your
>   modifications may be lost. By using a child theme you will ensure that
>   your modifications are preserved.

It's a good practice, to sum up.